# Where are files written to?

Tags: storage

We can see all our storage devices in `/dev/`. For example `/dev/sda` is the first storage device, and `/dev/sda1` is the first partition on the first storage device. But when we save to something else on the file system like `/usr/local/` How do we know which storage device our files are being written to?

Comment: Whichever one Ubuntu is installed on?

Comment: Okay, then how do I start writing data to my other storage devices?

Comment: You copy the files you want to them.

Comment: I see. But the device we are currently writing to (the one Ubuntu is installed on), is it accessible via /dev/?

Comment: During the installation process, you can manually set-up different partitions and mount-points, but that would be a more advanced technical installation question. For example, during install, you could mount `/usr/local/share` to `/dev/sdb1`, `/var/` to `/dev/sdb2`, etc...

Comment: It will be there. It is most likely `sda1`, but not for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** What's the output of `df --human`?

Comment: One does not write to devices (`/dev/sdb1`). One writes to the filesystem mounted on the device, e.g. `/opt`, or `/home`.  `df --human` shows the currently mounted filesystems. Read `man df`. `sudo fdisk -l` will list all the disk partitions on all your disks, mounted or not. Read `man fdisk`.

Comment: If we're talking about default installation where everything is set up as simple as possible , no dual boot, the / filesystem will be on the /dev/sda1 and swap( virtual memory ) on /dev/sda2.  Everything else under root will be also on sda1 . But there are many many ways to tweak it. I'll be posting an answer later im the day, cannot do a lot on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I was perusing through some questions on stackoverflow and came across this beautiful command.

```
df -P file/goes/here | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

for instance if I wanted to find out the drive **video.flv** is stored on, I'd do something like this

```
 df -P file/video.flv | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

also remember that you must be working on the current location of that file.
Correct me if I'm wrong but try that command. I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274354/how-to-find-out-mount-partition-a-directory-or-file-is-on-linux-server)